# ERROR: loop variable of FOREACH must be a known variable or list of variables

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have few FOREACH loops in my functions. The loops seem to perfectly agree with [the official postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html). This error message is returned:

```
ERROR: loop variable of FOREACH must be a known variable or list of variables
SQL state: 42601
```

Google found nothing for `postgresql "loop variable of FOREACH"`. I solved this somehow for my older foreach loops, but I don't remember how, and I can't find any difference that could be significant for the solution of this error.

I have PostgreSQL 9.3.4 and pgAdmin III 1.18.1 on Windows XP 32 bit. Here are interresting parts of the functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vloz_kont() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  _idmat integer;
  _nazmat text;
  _zast text;
  sj_nad text;
  ...
BEGIN

...

--bugged loop
FOREACH _mat IN ARRAY NEW._material::text[] LOOP
  SELECT split_part( _mat, ' ', 1 ) INTO _nazmat;
  SELECT rtrim( ltrim(split_part( _mat, ' ', 2 ), '(' ), ')' ) INTO _zast;
  SELECT id INTO _idmat FROM pro_material WHERE popis = _nazmat;
  IF _idmat IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO material_konst ( id_mat, kod_sj, kod_akce, zastoupeni )
    VALUES ( _idmat, NEW._kod_sj, NEW._kod_akce, _zast );
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO material_konst ( id_mat, kod_sj, kod_akce, jiny_nazev, zastoupeni )
    VALUES ( 8, NEW._kod_sj, NEW._kod_akce, _nazmat, _zast );
  END IF;
END LOOP;

...

--OK LOOP
FOREACH sj_nad IN ARRAY NEW._nad::text[] LOOP
  INSERT INTO s_vztah (nad, pod, kod_akce, typ_vztahu)
  VALUES(
    sj_nad,
    NEW._kod_sj,
    NEW._kod_akce,
    1
  );
END LOOP;

...

RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Both `_material` and `_nad` are text array columns of a view, as well as all other variables. The whole INSTEAD OF trigger function is too long to reproduce in entirety (almost 200 code rows) - `...` in the code sample represent skipped unrelated code.

So why is there the error, and how to solve it?

Comment: Show the rest of the function. Is there a `DECLARE` block?

Comment: @CraigRinger: answered by and edit. Adding whole context would make me show half the code of my whole project, which would obfuscate things a lot. I made sure everything matches the corresponding views and tables, so I don't want to include these if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing complete code, or a cut-down test case, it's hard to be sure but the error strongly suggests that:

```
FOREACH _mat
        ^^^^
        this variable is undeclared
```

Comment: You are right. I forgot this, so I even omitted the loop variable declaration for the working loop example in last update. I have corrected this now.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  loop variable of FOREACH must be a known variable or list of variables

When I tried to iterate an array with a [FOREACH statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
  FOREACH temp SLICE 0 IN ARRAY ARRAY['a','b','c'] LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', temp;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

So, I declared `temp` local variable as shown below, then the error was solved:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  temp VARCHAR; -- Here
BEGIN
  FOREACH temp SLICE 0 IN ARRAY ARRAY['a','b','c'] LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', temp;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

In addition, a [FOR statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-INTEGER-FOR) doesn't need a declared local variable when iterating numbers as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
  FOR num IN 1..3 LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', num;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

While, a [FOR statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-INTEGER-FOR) must need a declared local variable when iterating table's rows as shown below otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949337/psql-loop-variable-of-loop-over-rows-must-be-a-record-or-row-variable-or-list#77934106):

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  row RECORD; -- Here
BEGIN
  FOR row IN SELECT * FROM person LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', row;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```